# ansible : get roles from playbook in a subfolder

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I have this tree:

```
├── plays
│   ├── ansible.cfg
│   ├── playbook_01.yml
│   ├── playbook_02.yml
│   └── playbook_03.yml
├── README.rst
├── roles
│   ├── role_A
│   │   ├── files
│   │   └── tasks
│   │       └── main.yml
│   └── role_B
│       ├── files
│       └── tasks
│           └── main.yml
├── serverlist
│   ├── client1_serverlist_prod
│   ├── client1_serverlist_test
│   ├── client1_serverlist_train
│   ├── client2_serverlist_prod
│   ├── client2_serverlist_test
│   └── client2_serverlist_train
└── vagrant
    └── Vagrantfile
```

With ansible.cfg in play folder::

```
$ cat plays/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
roles_path=../roles/
$
```

I call from vagrant the ansible.playbook::

```
$ grep playbook vagrant/Vagrantfile
ansible.playbook = "../plays/playbook_01.yml
```

on playbook_01.yml::

```
$ cat plays/playbook_01.yml
- hosts: vagrant
  vars:
    user: fox
    home: /home/fox
  roles:
    - role_B
```

with role_B::

```
$ cat roles/role_B/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: Create user group
  group: name={{ user }} state=present

- name: Create home directory for user
  file: state=directory path={{ home }} group=www-data owner={{ user }}
$
```

But ansible when only went to see roles in play folder, I get this error::

```
vagrant$ vagrant provision
==> vagrant: Running provisioner: ansible...
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true
ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o
ForwardAgent=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s' ansible-playbook
--user=vagrant --connection=ssh --timeout=30 --limit='vagrant'
--inventory-file=/home/luis/lab/sandbox/akd-iac/stack/vagrant/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory
--sudo -vvvv ../plays/playbook_01.yml
ERROR: cannot find role in
~/stack/plays/roles/role_B or
~/stack/plays/role_B or /etc/ansible/roles/role_B
Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
vagrant$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it work just moving roles folder inside the plays folder and removing the play/ansible.cfg:

```
.
├── plays
│   ├── playbook_01.yml
│   ├── playbook_02.yml
│   ├── playbook_03.yml
│   └── roles
│       ├── role_A
│       │   ├── files
│       │   └── tasks
│       │       └── main.yml
│       └── role_B
│           ├── files
│           └── tasks
│               └── main.yml
├── README.rst
├── serverlist
│   ├── client1_serverlist_prod
│   ├── client1_serverlist_test
│   ├── client1_serverlist_train
│   ├── client2_serverlist_prod
│   ├── client2_serverlist_test
│   └── client2_serverlist_train
└── vagrant
    └── Vagrantfile
```

Details about the ansible.cfg configuration that make it work::

```
$ ls ~/.ansible.cfg
ls: cannot access ~/.ansible.cfg: No such file or directory

$ grep roles_path /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
#roles_path    = /etc/ansible/roles

$ echo $ANSIBLE_CONFIG

$
```

I still call from vagrant the ansible.playbook::

```
$ grep playbook vagrant/Vagrantfile
ansible.playbook = "../plays/playbook_01.yml
```

on playbook_01.yml::

```
$ cat plays/playbook_01.yml
- hosts: vagrant
  vars:
    user: fox
    home: /home/fox
  roles:
    - role_B
```

with role_B::

```
$ cat roles/role_B/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: Create user group
  group: name={{ user }} state=present

- name: Check Python version
  command: python --version
  register: pyver

- name: Print version
  debug:
    msg: "Python Version: {{ pyver.stderr }}"
```

With this modification that work like a charm:

```
$ vagrant provision
==> vagrant: Running provisioner: ansible...

PLAY [vagrant] ************************************************************
GATHERING FACTS ***********************************************************
  ok: [vagrant]
TASK: [role_B | Create user group] ****************************************
  ok: [vagrant]
TASK: [role_B | Check Python version] *************************************
  changed: [vagrant]
TASK: [role_B | Print version] ********************************************
  ok: [vagrant] => {
    "msg": "Python Version: Python 2.7.9"
}
PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************
vagrant                    : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
$
```

It look like that roles folder need to be inside the folder playbooks lives.

Answer (score 7):

You can probably use the variable [`roles_path`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#roles-path). It points to the folder where your roles are stored.

Comment: nop even with an abspath to the roles folder I still have the same error

Comment: Could you post the content of your file: `ansible.cfg` (if you are using it) and the Ansible version?

Comment: Ah! You can also try to set the `roles_path` variable in `ansible.cfg` and forget about paths in your playbook.

Comment: I've updated the question with the detail on plays/ansible.cfg file.
$ ansible --version say
   ansible 1.9.2,   configured module search path = None

Comment: Hi, sorry for being insistent in the same documentation page: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html. Please, take a look to the first few lines about the location of the `ansible.cfg` file. You mentioned your file is in `plays/ansible.cfg`, which doesn´t seem to be an standard path. Please, make sure that this file is in the correct place within your Vagrant Box AND enter the absolute path as the value of `roles_path`

Comment: So I've posted the content of my plays/ansible.cfg
I did try to remove this file and replace it by ~/.ansible.cfg with the same content but I get the same result. It seams that roles folder need to be inside the plays folder.

Comment: When you say: "~/.ansible.cfg", do you mean inside your Vagrant box or in your actual home directory? It´s a naive question, yes, but I´m afraid the behaviour you´re describing seems rather a human mistake than a bug.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned your `ansible.cfg` is not likely being picked up by ansible. You could test if your ansible.cfg is being picked up by setting this:

```
[defaults]
roles_path = ./isnasiblegettingmycfg
```

and checking the debug output. The ansible.cfg is [looked for in](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#configuration-file):

> - ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
> - ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
> - .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
> - /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

Roles are [looked for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#roles-path) in the directory of the executed playbook, and in the directory roles/ relative to the executed playbook and [roles_path](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#roles-path). So another simple solution is:

```
cd ~/stack/plays/ && ln -s ../roles
```

Comment: I'd like to know why `ansible.cfg` it's not picked up, as I am having a similar issue with the `roles_path`.

Answer (score 0):

the roles path can be provided directly

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#storing-and-finding-roles

or if you prefer, one can refer to it with :

```
roles:
- role: role_in_the_current_folder
- role: ../roles/role_in_an_other_folder
```